# Can I put displayable text in my CSS file?

Tags: html, css, text

Can I put text in my CSS file , and have that text be visible in the displayed HTML?

Comment: I have a question though. Why would you ever want to do this. Isn't the whole point of CSS to keep styling seperate from the HTML?

Comment: You might want to use the content property to insert the URL of a link after the link text in a print stylesheet.

Comment: Another use is to embed real quotation marks around something marked up with the <q> tag. Though I admit that the author of the question probably isn't thinking of something that subtle....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [content property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_gen_content.asp).

Comment: Just remember that it won't work in IE6, IE7, and IE8 will only work if you're properly including a DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

The content property is a good way of doing this. But make sure you use a !DOCTYPE tag or theres a good chance it won't work in IE8.

Comment: But I can't use 2 of this in one page.. stuped HTML why don't have p1,p2,p3....p54, like h1-h6

Comment: Because a hierarchy of headings makes sense and a hierarchy of paragraphs … doesn't.